# sctp_core_destroy(): SCTP API not initialized in kamailio start

Tags: websocket, sip, kamailio

Hi I have installed Kamalio it start first time but when I stop and start it again it gives sctp_core_destroy(): SCTP API not initialized . I have already installed sctp module.

```
 yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg

load_module(): could not find module <db_mysql> in </usr/lib/kamailio/modules>

[sctp_core.c:53]: sctp_core_destroy(): SCTP API not initialized
```

Answer (score 0):

From the log it is obvious that you have successfully compiled & installed SCTP module, however it could NOT be initialized.

Note that is error could must often than not be as a result of other errors in your cfg file.

Few tips:

- Can you run `kamailio -c` and to be sure there is NO error in your cfg.
- Found error? use this command to monitor what the exact issue is. Run from a different terminal `tail -fn200 /var/log/syslog`
- On the second terminal try restarting you Kamalio server `sudo service kamalio restart`
- Revisit terminal 1 and look out for the first line with CRITICAL output like the one below `CRITICAL: <core> [core/cfg.y:3413]: yyerror_at(): parse error in config file /usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg, line 366, column 41: syntax error`
- Line 366 mostly is the issue so visit that file at that line (366) to fix the proble
- `sudo nano +366 /usr/local/etc/kamailio/kamailio.cfg`

Let me know if it helps